# Release the memory

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code loads two parameters from a PHP file and prints them on the screen every second, but does that not use too much cpu/memory power to run it? How can that be avoided?
I want to free/release or autorelease the memory it's using, while it's updating, but I don't know how... Please help me out guys.

```
function updateStats(stat) {
  var stat = ["NAME","ID"];
  var url = "USERS.php";
  $.each(stat, function(i, key){
    $.post(url, {stats: key}, function(data) { // stats to stat
      $("#" + key).html(data);
    });
  });
}

setInterval(function(){
  updateStats("updateStats");
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Each of these variables is available for garbage collection after the `$.post` callback terminated. You cannot do manual memory management in JavaScript. However, you can set `stat` and `url` to `null` if you don't need them anymore. Note that your function parameter has the same name as the first variable you declare. The array will override whatever value you are passing to the function.

Comment: Are you currently having problems with memory consumption using this code? If not, you can stop worrying.

Comment: @ Felix Kling , where can i place stat and url to null???

Comment: @ Juhana no its not eating that big amount, but still.. but you right

Comment: @user1417815 It is not really necessary and won't help a lot. You gotta leave it to the garbage collector. If it's not broken, don't fix it. I'm sure there are bottlenecks in the other parts of your code that are more worth looking at.

Comment: I can't see any memory issues in your code. Are you experiencing some lags ?

Comment: @ Zakaria not that big amount maybe 2-3%, but i wonted to zero them, everytime the loop start over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript will automatically clear anything unused for you. There's no memory problems in this code.

Comment: But how can you put stat and url to null? when the loop going start over?

Comment: You shouldn't since you use them in your code on each iteration.